# How to add more FLAG of reason cause reboot with watchdog in Linux?

Tags: yocto, flags, reboot, watchdog, nxp-microcontroller

I'm using iMX8MM with Yocto. I'm trying to figure out the reason cause reboot with Watchdog.

I find out watchdog.h and there are a lot of FLAGs:

```
#define WDIOF_OVERHEAT 0x0001 /* Reset due to CPU overheat */
#define WDIOF_FANFAULT 0x0002 /* Fan failed */
#define WDIOF_EXTERN1 0x0004 /* External relay 1 */
#define WDIOF_EXTERN2 0x0008 /* External relay 2 */
#define WDIOF_POWERUNDER 0x0010 /* Power bad/power fault */
#define WDIOF_CARDRESET 0x0020 /* Card previously reset the CPU */
#define WDIOF_POWEROVER 0x0040 /* Power over voltage */
#define WDIOF_SETTIMEOUT 0x0080 /* Set timeout (in seconds) */
#define WDIOF_MAGICCLOSE 0x0100 /* Supports magic close char */
#define WDIOF_PRETIMEOUT 0x0200 /* Pretimeout (in seconds), get/set */
#define WDIOF_KEEPALIVEPING 0x8000 /* Keep alive ping reply */
```

But when I check with command, I get only 4 FLAGs:

```
$ wdctl

Device: /dev/watchdog
Identity: imx2+ watchdog [version 0]
Timeout: 60 seconds
Pre-timeout: 0 seconds
FLAG                   DESCRIPTION                          STATUS           BOOT-STATUS
KEEPALIVEPING          Keep alive ping reply                  1                   0
MAGICCLOSE             Supports magic close char              0                   0
PRETIMEOUT             Pretimeout (in seconds)                0                   0
SETTIMEOUT             Set timeout (in seconds)               0                   0
```

How do I get more of FLAG to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve the issue above.

1. Find all file concert about imx2+ watchdog package.
2. Modified by adding more flags as watchdog.h file.
3. Access menuconfig in Yocto and turn on some options in Watchdog sections. This action makes sure that bitbake recognize the changing in driver.
4. Rebuild and generate OS image.

Answer (score 1):

The macros(flags) you are seeing in the watchdog.h is the complete list. However, the application utility (here `wdctl`) is reading the driver capabilities implementation from the kernel.

Another flag you are seeing `WDIOF_OVERHEAT` and others should be supported by the kernel driver then and then only it will be available to the `wdctl` list.

Looking at the source code of the `wdctl` is working in the following way. It is calling the `read_watchdog_from_device` API to get the implemented flags(Environmental monitoring).

Please check for the flags in the corresponding driver from the i.MX8MM watchdog `imx2_wdt.c`.

References: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/wdctl.c
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt

Comment: I also tried to add flags to wdctl. And when I execute wdctl command, I can see all flags. I'm in test progress. With simplest case is overheat, it's seems to be working in the wrong way. My device is not rebooting, it shuts down. And I also can not read the caused of  the last reboot.